# Общий бордер для разных элементов

Tags: javascript, css3

Всем привет. Экспериментирую с CSS. Хочу узнать есть ли более простой способ задать border через CSS для разных элементов, которые между собой пересекаются, но в месте пересечения border'а быть не должно.

Вот пример:
https://codepen.io/TyronNIKO/pen/LYPXJJm

```html
<div class="circle big"></div>
<div class="circle small"></div>
<div class="circle small-oposite"></div>
<label for="r-pos">Change position X</label>
<input type="range" id="r-pos" oninput="changePos()" min="300" max="500" step="2"><br>
<label for="r-pos">Change Opacity</label>
<input type="range" id="r-opacity" oninput="changeOpacity()" min=".1" max="1" step=".01">
```

```css
html {
  --width:300px;
  --height:300px;
  --border:5px;
  --pos-small-Y:150px;
  --pos-small-X:450px;
  --opacity:1;
}
* {
  transition: 1s ease;
}
.circle {
  position:absolute; 
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.big {
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:var(--width);
  height:var(--height);
  z-index:2;
  background: green;
  opacity: var(--opacity);
  border: var(--border) solid #000;
}
.small {
  top:calc(var(--pos-small-Y) - var(--border));
  left:calc(var(--pos-small-X) - var(--border));
  width:calc(var(--width) - 50px);
  height:calc(var(--width) - 50px);
  z-index:1;
  background: blue;
  border: var(--border) solid #000;
}
.small-oposite {
  top:var(--pos-small-Y);
  left:var(--pos-small-X);
  width:calc(var(--width) - 50px);
  height:calc(var(--width) - 50px);
  z-index:3;
  background: green;
  opacity: var(--opacity);
  border: none;  
}
/**/
```

```js
let root = document.documentElement;
function changePos() {
  var inputSliderPos = document.getElementById('r-pos')
  root.style.setProperty('--pos-small-X',  inputSliderPos.value + 'px')
};
function changeOpacity() {
  var inputSliderOpc = document.getElementById('r-opacity')
  root.style.setProperty('--opacity',  inputSliderOpc.value)
};
```

В этом приме все работает вроде как надо, но, если я хочу задать прозрачность кругам, то все становиться явным...

Answer (score 0):

Легко. Делаем границу отдельным элементом и кладём с отрицательным `z-index`.

Вот, держи снеговика:

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -4px;
  background: black;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:4em"></div>
<div style="width:6em;margin-top:-1em"></div>
<div style="width:8em;margin-top:-2em"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть всё в ещё один блок и использовать фильтр с тенью, правда, поддержка браузерами пока так себе. Всё тот же снеговик:

```css
section {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0 4px black);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 4px black);
}

div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div style="width:4em"></div>
  <div style="width:6em;margin-top:-1em"></div>
  <div style="width:8em;margin-top:-2em"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Подложи еще один белый круг (или цвета фона страницы) под БОЛШОЙ кружочек (big) который совпадает с ним по контуру, круг перестанет быть прозрачным и пропускать бордер.